# Не перезаписывает данные пользователя в бд после обновления (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Metabox, в котором выводятся данные пользователя, можно обновить и перезаписать. После нажатия на кнопку обновить,данные высвечиваются прежние, а изменеия не происходят в бд.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'metatest_init');

function metatest_init() {
add_meta_box('metatest',
            'MetaTest-параметры поста', 'metatest_showup', 'post', 'side', 'high',  'default');
}

function metatest_showup($user, $box)
{

// получение существующих метаданных
$data = get_post_meta($user->ID, '_metatest_data', true);

// скрытое поле с одноразовым кодом
wp_nonce_field('metatest_action', 'metatest_nonce');

$user_info = get_userdata(1);
// поле с метаданными
echo '<p>Введите ID пользователя: <input type="text" name="metadata_field" value="' . $user_info->ID . '"/></p>';

echo '<p> Login:  <input type="text" name="metadata_field" value="' . $user_info->user_login . '"/></p>';

echo '<p>Имя:<br> <input type="text" name="metadata_field" value="' . $user_info->user_firstname . '"/></p>';

echo '<p>Фамилия: <input type="text" name="metadata_field" value="' . $user_info->user_lastname . '"/></p>';

echo '<p>E-mail : <input type="text" name="metadata_field" value="' . $user_info->user_email . '"/></p>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'metatest_save');

function metatest_save($userID) {
// пришло ли поле наших данных?
if (!isset($_POST['metadata_field']))
    return;
// не происходит ли автосохранение?
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return;
// не ревизию ли сохраняем?
if (wp_is_post_revision($userID))
    return;
// проверка достоверности запроса
check_admin_referer('metatest_action', 'metatest_nonce');

// коррекция данных
$data = sanitize_text_field($_POST['metadata_field']);

update_user_meta($userID, '_metatest_data', $data);
}
```

Comment: Вам только сегодня объяснили, что поля user_firstname и user_lastname не существуют. Ну как же так?

Comment: @KAGG Design, да, я помню, но я нашел у себя неточность, где я ошибся в прошлом вопросе. Я исправил это это у себя в коде. А в данном случае поле user_email даже не перезаписывается!

Comment: И потом, что вы хотите увидеть? После получения существующих метаданных в переменную $data она никак не используется.

Comment: @KAGG Design, к экшену подключается функция metatest_save, которая делает некоторые проверки обновляет строкой update_user_meta($userID, '_metatest_data', $data) данные по указанному ID

Comment: Вы кладёте рубль в левый карман, а потом пытаетесь вытащить его из правого.

Comment: @KAGG Design, Ваша фраза мне ни о чем не сказала!

Comment: Левый карман называется _metatest_data, а правый - get_userdata. Я уж и не знаю, как понятнее объяснить. Вы записываете в базу одно, а на экран выводите другое. Что тут непонятного?